# e%cc%82 = ê and i%cc%81 = í, what encode are these codes?

Tags: html, url, encoding

I need to know where I find these codes to overwrite them in my search using selenium + python.

Google don't show good results for searches using %. It simply don't consider %.

í should be %C3%AD, not i%cc%81, what I don't know about this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score 0):

"*`í` should be `%C3%AD`, not `i%cc%81`, what I don't know about this?*" It's [Unicode normalization](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/).

**Example** (Python):

```
import unicodedata
from urllib.parse import quote, unquote

encodedstr = 'e%cc%82 i%cc%81'
decodedstr = unquote( encodedstr )
print( '\n' + encodedstr, '=>', decodedstr)
for char in decodedstr:
  print( char, unicodedata.name(char).title())

decodedNFCstr = unicodedata.normalize( 'NFC', decodedstr)
encodedNFCstr = quote( decodedNFCstr) 
print( '\n' + encodedNFCstr, '=>', decodedNFCstr)
for char in decodedNFCstr:
  print( char, unicodedata.name(char).title())

print( '\n', decodedstr == unicodedata.normalize( 'NFD', decodedNFCstr) )
```

**Result**: `.\SO\67620897.py`

```
e%cc%82 i%cc%81 => ê í
e Latin Small Letter E
̂ Combining Circumflex Accent
  Space
i Latin Small Letter I
́ Combining Acute Accent

%C3%AA%20%C3%AD => ê í
ê Latin Small Letter E With Circumflex
  Space
í Latin Small Letter I With Acute

 True
```

The following screenshot shows decomposed characters raw (unprocessed, unlike the browser rendering engine):

[image: result]

Comment: Just one more question please:
how I can quote like e%cc%82 i%cc%81 instead %C3%AA%20%C3%AD ?

Comment: `e%cc%82 i%cc%81` is Copy&Paste from the question title.  However, `print( quote( unicodedata.normalize( 'NFD', 'ê í')))` returns `e%CC%82%20i%CC%81` (note quoted space as `%20`). So `quote( unicodedata.normalize( 'NFD', 'ê í')).replace('%20',chr(0x20))` yields the original string `e%CC%82 i%CC%81`.

Comment: Ahhh, I racked my brains thinking how to solve it, also tried unicodedata.normalize() alone, but it still fails. Thank you so much JosefZ.