# Converting Unicode for special characters in Python when extracting web data

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, type-conversion

I have byte information that needs to be converted into a string.

The byte information is as follows:  `byte_info = b'Set temp to 0 \\xf8C in 10 s'`.
I want to convert it into a string like this: `string = "Set temp to 0 °C in 10 s"`. Additionally, I need to decode the following characters:

- Dollar sign ($) decode from %24
- Colon (:) decode from %3A
- Caret (^) decode from %5E
- Tilde (~) decode from %7E

I tried

```py
for encoded_char, decoded_char in replacements.items():
    string = string.replace(encoded_char.decode('utf-8'), decoded_char)
```

where `replacements` is dict of key and value.

Also I tried with decode - latin and its not working.

Comment: [percent encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67620897/) and [How can convert '\\u5de5' into '\u5de5'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75737611/)

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

You can test this with following code.

```
byte = b'degree Celsius: = \xf8 , greater than or equal to: = \xf3' 
string = byte.decode('cp437') 
print(string)
```

for reference : https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Thanks for your support

Comment: The question shows `\\xf8`, i.e. the byte is double escaped, where as the answer uses `\xf8` which is not double escaped. If the text is not double escaped `byte_info.decode('cp437')` would work, if it is double escaped you'd need something like `byte_info.decode('unicode_escape').encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('cp437')`.